# Postback of a button happen after two clicks inside a Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Please see below image.
[image]

I have a admin page in my website.In there left side have a menu.It is treeview. when user click a tree node right side controls are loading. Right side controls are inside User Controls. So when we come to this page say we select category. Then right side panel display. So then after fill data when I click the Save button all data inside textboxes are cleared and no records go to DB. But then after fill the record and when I click button again then record goes. So After onwards you only have to click one. Records goes to DB.

So my question is why its not work at first time. I want to solve it

I load user controls using this code

```
            clearPHolderControls();
            JobCategoryControl JobCategoryControl = (JobCategoryControl)LoadControl("~/UC/Admin/JobCategoryControl.ascx");
            pHolderAdminContent.Controls.Add(JobCategoryControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more clear if you can post the post back code but my guess is that you have to check if the necessary code to load the right side controls are at right place so that post back is  not overriding the button click event.